# Two variable in one foreach

Tags: php, laravel

I need two variable in one foreach.
Now i'm having like this:

```
 @php $championships = \App\Models\Championship::all(); @endphp
    <div class="tour-list">
        @foreach($tours as $tour)
        <div class="tour-list-box row">
            <input type="text" value="{{$tour->name}}" class="col-md-3 input-styles">
            <input type="date" value="{{$tour->start_date}}" class="col-md-3 input-styles">
            <select name="" id="" class="col-md-3 input-styles">
                @foreach($championships as $championship)
                @if($championship->deleted)
                <option value="">select championship</option>

                @else
                <option value="">{{$championship->name}}</option>
                @endif

                @endforeach
                @if($tour->championship->deleted)
                @else
                <option selected value="">{{$tour->championship->name}}</option>
                @endif


            </select>
            <!-- all championships -->
            <span tour_id="{{$tour->id}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-left col-md-1 tour-remove-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span>
            <span championship_id="{{$championship->id}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right col-md-1 tour-edit-input"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span> </span>
        </div>
        @endforeach
    </div>
```

But it's repeated 2 times so i need this 2 variables $tours and $championships in one foreach.
I tried this:

```
 @foreach(array_combine($championships, $tours) as $championship => $tour)

@endforeach
```

But i'm getting error ' array_combine(): Argument #1 ($keys) must be of type array, '
is it passable to have 2 variables?

Thanks for answers <3

Comment: You have only one tour for one championship ? Or one championship per tour ? Or did you inverses championship and tour loops ?

Comment: One championship can have 2 tours

Comment: So you should outer loop on championship and inner loop on tours . Or may be reorganise your data to enable easier access to what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

First of all,it's not recommended to use the model directly inside the blade file,instead putt all this logic inside the controller and pass one variable to the view.

second,all eloquent are objects(collections) so you cant deal with them as array ,to treat them ass array you need `$championships = \App\Models\Championship::all()->toArray()`

third,`array_combine` — Creates an array by using one array for keys and another for its values you need to use `$array = array_unique(array_merge($array1, $array2));` instead to merge 2 arrays int one array containing only unique values

Comment: Hello thanks for answering i added to controller  $championshipsArray = Championship::all()->toArray();  but i can't understand how can i use it in here $array = array_unique(array_merge($array1, $array2));  i'm new in this stuff  )

Comment: I am sorry ,i will explain more ,I will edit the answer :

Comment: could you please explain more what  is the relation between tours and championships and what is it that you are trying to use the loop for ?

Comment: when i added tour there must be selected only one championship but when i will edit it there must be all championships so user can select another championship